# How to toggle modal windows in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have two buttons that triggers different modal windows, but I can't get to make when I click in one of the buttons (and trigger its corresponding modal window), if the other modal windows is opened, close the other. 
Simple as: if I open a modal and the other modal is opened, close the currently opened one and open the new. 
I'm using bootstrap modals.

This triggers one modal window

```
<button class="magicon" data-toggle="modal" 
         data-target="#modalsearch" data-backdrop="false"></button>
<div id="modalsearch" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" 
         role="dialog" aria-labelledby="labelmodalsearch" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

And this triggers the other

```
<button class="navicon" data-toggle="modal" 
         data-target="#modalmenu" data-backdrop="false"></button>
<div id="modalmenu" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" 
         role="dialog" aria-labelledby="labelmodalmenu" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

thanks for your help!

---

this is the working site, check how the magnifier glass icon and the hamburger icon behaves when opening their corresponding modal windows.

http://www.byalexander.com.au/rotary-youth-art-project-cc-x-ccp-2017-2/

Comment: Please add a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or use [SO snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: How can you click on button Without closing the First Open Modal.??Or the First modal contains the button to open the next Modal..

Comment: hey @Dwhitz, this is the working site, check the magnifier glass icon and the hamburger icon http://www.byalexander.com.au/rotary-youth-art-project-cc-x-ccp-2017/

Comment: hey @too_cool, this is the working site, check the magnifier glass icon and the hamburger icon http://www.byalexander.com.au/rotary-youth-art-project-cc-x-ccp-2017/

Comment: Do you use any JavaScript. If not, I would recommend it as you can then manage the behaviours of each modal. Close the other one (even if it is not open) before opening the next.

Comment: You're right @PeterSmith, certainly I could do it again from scratch, but as Bootstrap offers creating modal windows with no much effort I've noticed that there is no way of doing this natively on Bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

    $('.modal').not(this).modal('hide');

 });
 $('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {

   var $btnRelated = $(e.relatedTarget);
    $btnRelated.hasClass('open') && $btnRelated.removeClass('open');

 });
```

Code was updated, so the button states are also considered, as per your site.

Comment: You don't need to pass even (e) to the function, it is there from my 'still not edited answer'. Good luck!

Comment: Many thanks Levon, although it seems to be hiding the modals

Comment: Thanks Levon, tried but it's killing the modals, no modal triggers after clicking

Comment: I just used it on your page, and when you click search, navmenu is closing, and search modal opening..... and vice versa, the only problem is now pending for you is remove hamburger active state accordingly.... I'll now add the workaround

Comment: Hey Juan, I saw my workaround is there on your site :) please mark as solution , Thanks!